# Link to an anckor tag in another page does not work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a link in page1(www.example.com/page2.html#idd) that refers to an anchor tag in page2
when i click on the link(www.example.com/page2.html#idd) in page1 i just go to page2(www.example.com/page2.html) and not to the #idd.
I think something wrongs with "js" file but i don't know what!

```
"index.js"

$('.form').find('input, textarea').on('keyup blur focus', function (e) {

var $this = $(this),
  label = $this.prev('label');

  if (e.type === 'keyup') {
        if ($this.val() === '') {
      label.removeClass('active highlight');
    } else {
      label.addClass('active highlight');
    }
  } else if (e.type === 'blur') {
    if( $this.val() === '' ) {
        label.removeClass('active highlight');
        } else {
        label.removeClass('highlight');
        }
  } else if (e.type === 'focus') {

  if( $this.val() === '' ) {
        label.removeClass('highlight');
        }
  else if( $this.val() !== '' ) {
        label.addClass('highlight');
        }
 }

});

$('.tab a').on('click', function (e) {

e.preventDefault();

$(this).parent().addClass('active');
$(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('active');

target = $(this).attr('href');

$('.tab-content > div').show();

$(target).fadeIn(600);

});
```

here is the html file:

```
"page1.html"


<div> <a href="example.com/page1.html#idd">click here</a>
```

`"page2.html"`

```
 <div id="idd">content......</div>
```

Comment: Java is not JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

That's not an anchor, that's a `div`.  And this has nothing to do with JavaScript.  (Unless you're writing JavaScript code to mimic the behavior of linking to an anchor on a page, which you don't appear to be doing in the code shown.)

To go directly to an anchor, it needs to be an anchor with the expected name:

```
<a name="idd">content......</a>
```

You could, for example, add such an anchor to your `div`:

```
<div id="idd">
    <a name="idd">some label</a>
    content......
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to use javascript but a simple HTML code. 
in page1.html :
 `<a href="example.com/page2.html#idd">click here</a>` 
in page2.html : `<a name="idd"></a>`